# Sharepoint list and Word form integration

Tags: word

I  must say it's a great forum to post your questions and discuss some of the issues and challenges with individuals with expert SP knowledge.

I was wondering if someone could advise if it’s possible to create a Word template for users to input data and save documents as standalone documents on Sharepoint document library.

The second part which is a bit of challenge to fathom is if data from these individual documents can be stored in the sharepoint lists.

I have come up with the solution keeping in mind the limitations – as I don’t have Sharepoint server otherwise I’d have used Infopath forms and also I am not allowed to use Sharepoint Designer. Do you think is there any other way this can be achieved?

Will appreciate your advise.
Thanks,
Shoro